# How to undistort a larger image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have performed calibration using a set of 480 x 640 px images.

Now, I have an image that is enlarged to 960 x 1280 px and I want to undistort it.

I have tried:

```
img = cv2.imread('enlargedimage.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramatrix, _ = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx * 2,  dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))
dst = cv2.undistort(st, mtx * 2 , dist, None, newcameramatrix)
cv2.imwrite('doublesize.png', dst)
```

thinking that I would need to double the matrix values and it would work, but it is not.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Check out this tutorial by opencv
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

Answer (score 1):

We need to scale just fx, fy, cx and cy.

so, I removed mtx * 2 that scaled mtx[2][2] which needs to stay 1 and then scaled other mtx values accordingly worked for me.